# Error Notice: Undefined offset: 0 al obtener datos PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, poo, pdo

Al usar la siguiente función me saca ese error, la función sirve para verificar si existe o no la cadena en la `DB`, si existe no saca ese error, pero si no existe me sale el error

> "Notice: Undefined offset: 0"

Ya he verificado el código, la conexión con la DB y todo está correcto. Esta función ya la había usado en anterioridad en otra página, y me funcionaba correctamente, pero ahora que lo he pasado a otro proyecto, no me funciona y me cercioré de que todo estuviera bien escrito.

```
<?php

function selectUser($username){
    try{
      $con = connect();
      $query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user = :user";
      $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute(array(
      ':user' => $username
      ));
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
        return $result;
        $con = null;
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        return 'Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Pero ¿el `Undefined offset: 0` es en ese código o es cuando recuperas el resultado de la comprobación? ¿Puedes mostrar cómo usas lo que devuelve tu función `selectUser` cuando la llamas? Creo que el problema está ahí, ya que `fetchAll()` devuelve un array vacío cuando no hay datos y si intentas acceder a algún índice de ese array vacío tendrás el aviso `Undefined offset`

Comment: El código devuelve un array que al usarlo con $result[0]["user"] por ejemplo me devuelve el usuario del que se haya especificado en la función. Aparte de eso, como ya dije antes, ya había usado esa función en otro proyecto y me había funcionado correctamente usando el fetchAll, así que creo que ese no es el problema. No obstante si conoces alguna manera en la que me pueda devolver los valores que se han buscado de la db me vendría bien.

Comment: $s = selectUser("d");
echo $s[0]["user"];

Comment: Sí conozco una manera, pero para darte una respuesta con fundamento es necesario que indiques cómo manejas la respuesta. No sé si me entiendes. Cuando tu llamas a la función tú haces algo como esto, supongo: **`$datos=selectUser($username);`**, para este caso lo importante **el manejo que haces de la variable `$datos`, a posteriori. Una manera es: `if($datos){//trabajar con los datos ya que hay un resultado}else{echo "No se encontraron registros";}`.

Comment: Correcto, justo lo que yo creía, ahora te escribo una solución...

Comment: Perfecto gracias, la verdad estoy bien perdido, porque antes si me funcionaba sin problema :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código de la función está bien.

### El problema

El problema está en el manejo que haces del resultado obtenido a posteriori.

```
$s = selectUser("d"); 
echo $s[0]["user"];
```

Cuando no hay resultados, `fetchAll` devuelve un array vacío, por lo tanto, no puedes acceder a `$[0]` en ese caso, ya que el array vacío que está devolviendo `fetchAll` no tiene un índice `0`, de ahí la Noticia:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

### La solución

Puedes verificar la no nulidad de `$s` antes de trabajar con los datos.

Algo así:

```
$s = selectUser("d"); 

if ($s){
    echo $s[0]["user"]; 
}else{
    echo "No se encontraron datos"; 
}
```

---

Si quieres leer todas las filas obtenidas, puedes modificar el código así:

```
$s = selectUser("d"); 

if ($s){
    $strHTML="";
    foreach ($s as $row){
        $strHTML.=$row["user"];
        //$strHTML.=" - ". $row["otra-columna-del-select"];
        $strHTML.=PHP_EOL; //Esto es un salto de línea
    }
    echo $strHTML;
}else{
    echo "No se encontraron datos"; 
}
```

Lo que he hecho ha sido básicamente:

- Crear una variable llamada `$strHTML` a la cual ir concatenando los resultados de las diferentes filas (se puede hacer de otro modo, a mi me gusta escribir código limpio).
- Abrir un ciclo `for` que recorra la variable `$s`, e ir sacando de ella los diferentes valores de cada columna y de cada fila. En `$row["..."]` tienes que poner el nombre de columna (como se llaman en la tabla) de cada valor que quieras.
- Al final de cada ciclo añado la constante `PHP_EOL` (salto de línea) a la cadena de concatenación.
- **Fuera del bucle** imprimo todo el resultado obtenido en `$strHTML`.

Quedará algo así más o menos:

```
Usuario X  -  otro valor de otra columna ...
Usuario Y  -  otro valor de otra columna ...
Usuario Z  -  otro valor de otra columna ...
```

De este modo puedes crear una tabla, llenar un formulario con los valores, etc, etc, etc.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Estabas en lo correcto, pero el problema es que lo que yo necesito es que seleccione los datos que recorra en la db y los almacene en un array, sería mucha molestia que me ayudaras con ese pedazo?

Comment: Eso ya lo tienes. El valor de `$s`, cuando encuentra datos, es un array con todos los datos, luego esos datos los puedes leer dentro de un bucle. Ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo solucioné, estaba bastante claro xD

Comment: Perfecto @Astaroth, me alegro de que tu problema se haya resuelto. Saludos y bienvenido a nuestra comunidad, uno de los mejores sitios para aprender a programar y para recibir ayuda. Espero que no dejes de pasar por aquí para recibir ayuda o para ayudar, cuando sea el momento. Saludos.